# Receiving JPEG images via http GET request

Tags: c++

I want to receive images from an IP camera over HTTP via GET request. I have written a program that creates TCP socket connection with the camera and sends the following GET request to the camera:

```
GET /mjpeg?res=full HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 143.205.116.14\r\n\r\n
```

After that, I receive images with the following function in a while loop:

```
while((tmpres = recv(sock,(void *) buf, SIZE, 0)) > 0 && check<10)
```

.....

where `SIZE` represents the size of the buffer. I, infact, don't know what size to define here. I am receiving a color image of size 2940x1920. So I define `SIZE=2940x1920x3`. After receiving the MJPEG image, I decode it with ffmpeg. But I observe that ffmpeg just partially/uncorrectly decodes the image and I just see a half (or even less) of the image. I assume it could be a size problem. 
Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Regards,

Khan

Comment: actually the size will be much smaller, MJPEG is used not to encrypt the data, but to compress them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel (for the umpteenth time)? Use a ready-made HTTP client library, such as [`libcurl`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).

For that matter, perhaps you can even just write your entire solution as a shell script using the `curl` command line program:

```
#!/bin/sh

curl -O "http://143.205.116.14/mjpeg?res=full" || echo "Error."
curl -o myfile.jpg "http://143.205.116.14/mjpeg?res=full" || echo "Error."

# ffmpeg ...
```

Comment: I have already tried curl, it doesn't save the image. Instead, I see some garbage data at the console. Moreover, the continuous stream is only obtained through GET method. That's why I had to write a socket program for sending the GET request to the camera and receiving images.

Comment: If you see garbage on stdout you probably didn't specify the output options (`-o` or `-O`), see my edited post. curl is an HTTP client, anything you can do via HTTP can be done with it in one way or another...

Comment: Now I can receive a single image with your command. Shell script is not my preferred way. I want to capture images in a C++ application where I can do some image processing with the images. So what I need is the image buffer. What this command is doing is that it simply saves an image to disk. Instead of saving it to disk, I want to have it in a memory buffer. Moreover, the above command brings only a single image. For continuous image capture, I will have to use GET as command (as I specified in my very first post). How to use GET command with CURL?

Comment: Curl uses GET by default. What you will probably have to do is run curl in a loop. It depends on the specifics of your server, though, e.g. how often does it produce a new image, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Save bytes received as binary file and analyze. May be an incomplete image (image can be encoded as  progressive JPEG - is interlaced in fact - that means if you truncate the file you'll see horizontal lines.) or can be a ffmpeg decoding issue. Or something different. What is `check < 10`  condition ?

Comment: I have observed the bytes received in one call of recv function. The bytes received don't represent the complete image. I think the image is being sent in the forms of separate packets. I also tried to call recv function in a loop where it receives data upto the size of the image, but to no avail. Here the recv function just hangs.

Comment: but of course you don't receive the hole image in a single recv call. This is your problem. After each call you should copy (append) data from receive buf to a different buffer, and use that one

Comment: The camera manual says that "in response to the GET request, the camera sends a continuous stream of images separated by the boundary separator "fbdr" in accordance with MIME multipart/x-mixed-replace format. The question is how do I detect this boundary so that I can receive data until the boundary is detected and then convert/decode the received data into image format?

Comment: I receive the images continuously until the received bytes become zero. I, then, decode the received buffer into JPEG format and this gives me a complete and correct JPEG image. But I can do this only to receive a single image. I don't know why the received bytes become zero. I am not able to receive the next image. Here is how I receive the data:

Comment: while(tmpres>0)  
{  
  tmpres = recv(sock,&buf[index], bytesleft, 0);  
  bytesleft=bytesleft-tmpres;  
  index=index+tmpres;  
  bytesreceived=bytesreceived+tmpres;  
 }

Comment: looks fine. recv return zero because stream has ended. If you need to receive more than one image in the same stream you should analyze the format of the received packet. It is most probably MIME (like the email). if so, extrat images and voila.

Comment: I suppose you receive a single image because you are requesting only one. Only camera manual can help.

Comment: The manual says that in response to the request "GET /image?res=full&x0=0&y0=0&x1=2944&y1=1920 HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: 143.205.116.14\r\n\r\n", the camera sends a continuous stream of images separated by the boundary separator "fbdr" in accordance with the MIME type. So, it's a bit surprising why recv function returns zero after the completion of an image. I don't know how to know when an image has been received completely. I just know this when the recv returns zero, and of course it doesn't capture the next image then.

Comment: OK. Now I can receive the sequence of images. But the only problem is that I don't know what would be the size of the incoming image (which keeps varying). For this, I define a very large size resulting in a huge delay between the successive images. Is there any way to know the size of the coming image? Why the size of the image keeps changing?

Comment: the size vary because is jpg and compression algorithm performs worse of better. If size is not somewhere in MIME header, you cannot know what will be. As buffer you should use a circular buffer or better a memory stream.

Comment: Well...I have just observed that the delay between the successive images is due to hundreds of recv() function call (around 700-800) because in one call, recv() returns around 1400-2000 bytes, so that I have to run it repeatedly to fill the entire buffer. Is there any way to increase the number of received bytes in a single call of recv() function? I am using the TCP socket connection with SOCK_STREAM as follows: sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)